# Binary Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double' and 'Element' (aka 'AnyObject')

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, for-loop

```
let totalPrice: Double = price * value
var money: Double = 0
for totalPrice in dataArray {
    money = money + totalPrice
}
```

Unable to assign binary operator '+'

Answer (score 0):

How is "dataArray" declared?

Is it a [AnyObject] or [Double]

If it's the former, you'll need to cast it as a double by using:

```
guard let price = totalPrice as? Double else { continue }
money = money + totalPrice
```

Comment: dataArray is NSMutableArray

Comment: Give the above code a shot as an NSArray/NSMutableArray is similar (but not equivalent to a swift [AnyObject] array. Because what is input is not specifically cast upon the Array's creation you have to cast it using an "as?" I do recommend you use a swift array rather than the old NSArray/NSMutableArray though. You don't need to cast it if you declare it [Double]. The compiler can also optimize a statically typed array better than a dynamically allocated one.

Answer (score 0):

totalPrice is type of `Element`. I think there should be some kind of amount which is typed of `Double` don't you?

Also when you are dealing with currency data check `NSDecimalNumber`. `Double` will lose significant numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your **dataArray** is array of type **AnyObject**. If it really contain doubles, you can iterate like this:

```
for totalPrice in dataArray as! [Double] {
    money = money + totalPrice
}
```